# Discord.py missing argument exception

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command that requires the user to enter a string that could possibly be two words long. Currently, I am using this code:

```py
    @client.command(name="Claim")
    async def Claim(ctx, response, response2):
        response = response.lower()
        response2 = response2.lower()
        response += "-"
        response += response2
        print(response)
        for answer in answers:
            if response in answer["name"]:
                await ctx.send(f"Congratulations!{ctx.author.mention}\nYou won:\n{answer['name']} x{answer['amount']}")
```

When I enter one word, I get a `MissingRequiredArgument` error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: response2 is a required argument that is missing

How can I use an exception to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using an exception to handle this, you can just use one argument that accepts multiple words.

```
    @client.command(name="Claim")
    async def Claim(ctx, *, response):
        response = response.lower()
        print(response)
        for answer in answers:
            if response in answer["name"]:
                await ctx.send(f"Congratulations!{ctx.author.mention}\nYou won:\n{answer['name']} x{answer['amount']}")
```